# Delphi Firemonkey FMX Display double byte strings from MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, firemonkey, double-byte

I'm trying to display double-byte characters in my firemonkey app - windows & android.

```
Query1.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT ITEM_NAME_KR FROM items WHERE ItemID=1';
Query1.Open;
showmessage( Query1.fieldbyname('ITEM_NAME_KR').AsString );
Edit1.Text := Query1.fieldbyname('ITEM_NAME_KR').AsString;
```

The MySQL field is set to utf8 with utf8_unicode_ci encoding.  I know this is correct because when I update it in MySQL Bench, it displays the double byte correctly in Bench.

I've even tried adding a persistent field for WideString field for ITEM_NAME_KR but it gives me an error : "FDQuery1: Type mismatch for field 'ITEM_NAME_KR', expecting: wideString actual: String".

I've searched quite a few articles but I can't see any special mention of how to display double-byte characters in firemonkey apps - both Windows / Android.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is, since you didn't post any output from the DB. But since ``Delphi 2009`` the ``string`` type switched to ``Unicode``, so each character is already 2 bytes long!

Comment: apologies... the string output was 3 question marks - ???  (there were 3 double-byte characters). would Win32 be an issue?

Comment: No, Win32 is not an issue.

Comment: then any reason it just displays a ???   If MySQL WorkBench can display the chinese message, I believe my Delphi apps should be able to display it.  Do you have a small sample of an FMX app that can display double byte?

Comment: No, I don't have an example, sry. What happens when you put the DB data in a string var of type ``RawByteString``?

Comment: var
      LName : RawByteString;
    begin 
      ....
      LName := lQuery.fieldbyname('ITEM_NAME_KR').value;
      showmessage( LName );
      button2.text := LName;

Same output : "???"
It doesn't display double-byte, but no issue putting double-byte into the
button2.text from Delphi designer itself - will display.

It's the MySQL that's giving "???" instead of proper double bytes.

Comment: What **exact** column type and width is the ITEM_NAME_KR column on your server, varchr() or what?  And what engine type is it?

Comment: it's varchar(100).  using innodb